# Optimized selection of aggregated values with filtering using JPA Specifications

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have following problem - I need to select aggregated (summary) data from DB. There will be a lot of filters which will be dynamically changed and this functionality of filtering is already supported and implemented using Spring Data JPA Specifications which I would like to use.

I would like to optimize actual solution, which is working but consumes a lot of memory. I need to sum all user's salaries, number of children and get their average age due to specifications. I have method like this

```
public List<User> findAll(Specification<User> userSpecification)
```

I can retrieve list of all users matching filter criteria and iterate over them and aggregate required values in Java, which is working perfect. But if number of fetched users is too big, there is a lot of consumed memory what is problem.

In my opinion it would be much better to aggregate these values in DB and return only 3 numbers from DB to Java -> sum user's salaries, number of all them children and average age of selected users.

Could somebody help me what would be optimal solution?? Or is there way how to combine JPA Specifications with returning only aggregated data from DB to Java??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, you can't combine custom queries with Specifications. It's possible to re-use your specifications with the `CriteriaBuilder` API and use that to query your database.
Assuming the following projection:

```
public class AggregatedUserDetails {
  private long salarySum;
  private double ageAverage;
  private long childrenSum;

  public AggregatedUserDetails(long salarySum, double ageAverage, long childrenSum) {
    this.salarySum = salarySum;
    this.ageAverage = ageAverage;
    this.childrenSum = childrenSum;
  }
  // Getters & setters...
}
```

You can do the following (I've made some assumptions about your User entity...):

Update: Please note that the "Facade" portion of the `UserDetailsFacade` class name refers to an Application Facade from the book Analysis Patterns (Fowler, 1997)

```
@Component
public class UserDetailsFacade {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public UserDetailsFacade(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public AggregatedUserDetails aggregatedUserDetails() {
    return aggregatedUserDetails(null);
  }

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public AggregatedUserDetails aggregatedUserDetails(Specification<User> userSpecification) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<AggregatedUserDetails> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(AggregatedUserDetails.class);
    Root<User> from = query.from(User.class);

    Predicate predicate = null;

    if ( userSpecification != null )
      predicate = userSpecification.toPredicate(from, query, criteriaBuilder);

    CompoundSelection<AggregatedUserDetails> construct = criteriaBuilder.construct(
        AggregatedUserDetails.class,
        criteriaBuilder.sum(from.get("salary")),
        criteriaBuilder.avg(from.get("age")),
        criteriaBuilder.sum(from.get("children"))
    );

    CriteriaQuery<AggregatedUserDetails> select = query.select(construct);

    if ( predicate != null )
      select.where(predicate);

    return entityManager.createQuery(select).getSingleResult();
  }
}
```

That'll allow you to use your Spring Specifications whilst avoiding the overhead of retrieving all matching entities and computing the value within the application:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class UserDetailsFacadeTest {
  @TestConfiguration
  public static class UserDaoTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsFacade getUserDao(EntityManager entityManager) {
      return new UserDetailsFacade(entityManager);
    }
  }

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsFacade userDetailsFacade;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    User tom = new User();
    User dick = new User();
    User sally = new User();

    tom.setAge(17);
    dick.setAge(40);
    sally.setAge(35);

    tom.setChildren(0);
    dick.setChildren(1);
    sally.setChildren(0);

    tom.setSalary(240);
    dick.setSalary(40000);
    sally.setSalary(40000);

    userRepository.save(tom);
    userRepository.save(dick);
    userRepository.save(sally);
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetExpectedSummedSallary() {
    AggregatedUserDetails aggregatedUserDetails = userDetailsFacade.aggregatedUserDetails();
    assertThat(aggregatedUserDetails.getSalarySum(), is(80240L));
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetExpectedAverageAge() {
    AggregatedUserDetails aggregatedUserDetails = userDetailsFacade.aggregatedUserDetails();
    assertThat(Math.round(aggregatedUserDetails.getAgeAverage()), is(31L));
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetExpectedSummedChildren() {
    AggregatedUserDetails aggregatedUserDetails = userDetailsFacade.aggregatedUserDetails();
    assertThat(Math.round(aggregatedUserDetails.getChildrenSum()), is(1));
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetExpectedSummedSallaryOver1k() {
    AggregatedUserDetails aggregatedUserDetails = userDetailsFacade.aggregatedUserDetails(
        (Specification<User>) (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.ge(root.get("salary"), 1000));
    assertThat(aggregatedUserDetails.getSalarySum(), is(80000L));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
// com.example.demo.dao.UserDetailsFacadeTest#testGetExpectedAverageAge
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)

// com.example.demo.dao.UserDetailsFacadeTest#testGetExpectedSummedChildren
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select sum(user0_.salary) as col_0_0_, avg(cast(user0_.age as double)) as col_1_0_, sum(user0_.children) as col_2_0_ from user user0_

// com.example.demo.dao.UserDetailsFacadeTest#testGetExpectedSummedSallaryOver1k
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select sum(user0_.salary) as col_0_0_, avg(cast(user0_.age as double)) as col_1_0_, sum(user0_.children) as col_2_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.salary>=1000

// com.example.demo.dao.UserDetailsFacadeTest#testGetExpectedSummedSallary
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (id, age, children, salary) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select sum(user0_.salary) as col_0_0_, avg(cast(user0_.age as double)) as col_1_0_, sum(user0_.children) as col_2_0_ from user user0_
```

Comment: Perfect explanation and example .. Thank you so much :) I need to solve some other things like rounding values before sum them and so on but this is the way which I looked for ... :)

Comment: You should be able to dynamically construct your selection criteria also. The Criteriabuilder API isn't the nicest API to work with but it's very flexible - just don't get caught in the trap of making it too flexible as that can add a lot of unnecessary complexity! Good luck with the rest of the development.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by executing a native SQL query which does the aggregate:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a,b,c from ...");
List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();
```

The result list would contain one Object[] per row. I assume that your statement will return only one row, right? You may cast the object array to access the content:

```
String     a= (String)     result.get(0)[0];
Long       b= (Long)       result.get(0)[1];
BigDecimal c= (BigDecimal) result.get(0)[2];
```

If you are unsure which Java types are returned, set a breakpoint and inspect the result list with your debugger. Of course this is documented somewhere and also depends on configuration.

Instead of using Object you can tell JPA to map the result to a POJO Object:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a,b,c from ...", MyResult.class);
List<MyResult> result = q.getResultList();
```

In this case, myResult must contain attributes with matching names and types, for example:

```
class MyResult {
    private String a;
    private Long b;
    private BigDecimal c;

    // add setters ang getters here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes this solution would work, if there would be fixed filter (WHERE clause). But I need to dynamically change WHERE clause and conditions inside it. That is reason why I want to use JPA Specifications - to build part inside where condition dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried using a projection to bring back only the data required? Failing that could you not fall back to the criteria API?

Comment: Projection in combination with JPA Specifications is limited. You can use it, but it behaves differently as typical projection (without Specifications) -> It will fetch everything into the memory and after that it maps it to the projection. Maybe it is a little bit better solution but, it would be still only small optimalization.

Comment: Specifications aren't part of JPA, they're a DDD concept supported by Spring Data. It's hard to give a more definitive answer without seeing how the data is structired and needs to be aggregated. If it can be mapped to a projection (if the queries above can be grouped into a valid, singular JPA query) then that would be how I'd do it.

Comment: Yes of course, I thought Spring Data JPA Specifications .. 

Imagine that you have entity User with 100 attributes - you need to support filtering due to different attributes (this is part when I would like to use JPA Specifications).. And the result should be aggregated values (e.g. sum of some user attributes for all matched users, due to filter criteria - e.g sum of attribute salary of all matched users) ... If e.g. 100000 users matches filter criteria, it doesnt make sense to load all of them into the memory (even if it would be only one or few attributes - in case of projection)

Comment: Can you elaborate your code a bit more, or create a simplified equivalent? I appreciate you can't always share your code verbatim as it may be work related. You can still use your specification along with the criteria API - I'm not 100% sure but I think you're right that spring data can't handle avg and sum within a query using a specification. That being said if this is being encapsulated and doesn't require much more than varying filtering predicates you could use the criteria API and build the query programmatically adding the predicate as required.

Comment: You can also generate the where expression by concatenating string fragments. This is sometimes easiert (or more flexible) in case of compelx queries, specially when you join more or less other tables depending on the dynamic search criteria. You can also use parameters like ":userid" in combination with setParameter(). See https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter